# Array size declared by function leads to stack corruption, but clean compilation?

Tags: c++, arrays, gdb, address-sanitizer, stack-corruption

This is a code sample that I managed to extract from an original source code that compiles cleanly but crashes in a more or less random manner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

class base
{
    public:

        base() {}
        virtual const char f(void) = 0 ;
};

class d1 : public base
{
    static const char s = 15;

    public:

        d1()
        {
        }

        const char f()
        {
            return s;
        }
};

class d2 : public base
{
    static const char n = 25;

    public:

        d2()
        {
        }

        const char f()
        {
            return n;
        }
};

void method(char* p, size_t len)
{
    memset(p, 0, ((len * sizeof(char)) + 10));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    base *p = NULL;


    if(argc == 2)
    {
        printf("p shall be instance of d2\n");
        p = new d2();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("p shall be instance of d1\n");
        p = new d1();
    }

    char arr[p->f()];

    printf("Size of arr is %d\n", sizeof(arr));
    method(arr, p->f());

}
```

After some debug sessions with GDB and Address Sanitizer tools we've found that:

```
char arr[p->f()];
```

is the one to blame for the stack corruption.

Knowing that p is instantiated at runtime and that array size declaration is done at compile time with a fixed value, how does this compile without complaining? What is the value of p->f() at compile time?

Also, why does memset (writing an extra 10 bytes of an "undetermined" array size) run without a segmentation fault?

Comment: Are you using gcc/clang?  It is a extension that is on by default for those.

Comment: [Does not compile cleanly.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62ef3e46c5ee6a37) Are you talking about the GnuC++ dialect? If so, please make that explicit.

Comment: Your memset() in the method() funciton overruns your array by 10 bytes., which might corrupt the stack. You might get random behavior, you might get a crash. You are likely also be using a compiler that supports VLA in C++ (which means your array is sized at runtime, not at compile time).

Answer (score 3):

This is why you should always compile with warnings enabled. In this case, the relevant one is:

```
main.cpp:66:20: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]
     char arr[p->f()];
                    ^
```

(Note that there are other warnings, this is just the relevant one). [Variable length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) are permitted by gcc as an extension, which is why your code compiled. But had you seen this warning, presumably you would've made a different decision. `-Wall -Wextra` is your friend.

> Also, why does memset (writing an extra 10 bytes of an "undetermined" array size) run without a segmentation fault?

Undefined behavior is undefined, it doesn't necessarily require a segmentation fault.

Comment: The comments I use:  "-ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual   -O0 " with g++ on ubuntu